# What is a private Tor network

Tags: configuration, onion-services, network-configuration

While reading about botnets leveraging Tor hidden services for command and control I came across a term I have never seen or read about anywhere a private Tor network I tried researching this term however could not find anything that answered my question what is a Tor private network and how would someone set one up? To be clear I am not asking about the benefits and downsides I am only asking what it is the pros and cons already have a answer at [Private Tor networks: what are the benefits, and how would it be accomplished?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4424/private-tor-networks-what-are-the-benefits-and-how-would-it-be-accomplished)